# How to Show Map Scale Bar on android v2 map

Tags: android, api, dictionary, google-maps-api-2

I am working with Google API v2 map Android, but I cannot show the scale bar on it. Please help me, is there anything I can do to show scale bar on my map?
I am looking for it, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Google removed it in v2.
They removed it from their maps app but added it lately, don't know when they are gonna provide it for the developers.